# Issue in resetting the fields

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to reset all the fields except the fields which has "ignoreField" as one of their class.
I used below code but it is not working:

```
$('#feedback-form').not('input[class=ignoreField]')[0].reset();
```

Any idea?

Comment: you try to ignore fiedls with class `ignore` by checking the class `ignoreField` which is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi This can probably solve you problem:

Use of Not function will give you all the controls that do not have the class ignorefield and then clear it's value.

```
$('#feedback-form input').not('.ignoreField').val('');
```

Comment: only $('#feedback-form')[0].reset(); is working but it is resetting all the fields.

Comment: I guess there is some problem in the markup . Can you provide a js fiddle??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#feedback-form input').not('.ignoreField').reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#feedback-form input').not('.ignoreField').reset();
```

This should work